# Как удалить строку из файла, используя PHP?

Tags: php, строки, txt

Получаю строку:

```
$task = $_POST['tasks'];
```

Нужно удалить её из файла

```
$file = 'data/'.$_COOKIE["usernamecookie"].".txt";
```

Допустим, содержимое строки `cat`, а содержимое файла `dog, cat, bird`. Результат должен быть `dog, bird`...

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Читаем файл > ищем данные > удаляем > записываем обратно файл

Comment: Можно код пожалуйста? Процесс то я понимаю, у меня с кодом проблемы.

Comment: [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php()), [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php), [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Все работает, Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```
  $content = file_get_contents($file);
  $content = str_replace($task.”, ” ,””, $content);
  file_put_contents($file, $content);
```